# c# комбинаторика, уникальная позиция

Tags: c#, linq, комбинаторика

Мой код генерирует комбинации. Подскажите как с помощью LINQ можно убрать комбинации, позиция которых повторяется? Пример на цифрах

Такой результат я ожидаю:

```
1 2 3
2 3 1
3 1 2


public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int count)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (count == 1)
            yield return new T[] { item };
        else
        {
            foreach (var result in GetPermutations(items.Except(new[] { item }), count - 1))
                yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(result);
        }

        ++i;
    }
}
Результат моего кода:
1 2 3
1 3 2
и т.д
```

Comment: Объясните, что значит "позиция которых повторяется"

Comment: @MBo , Имелось ввиду то, что если "1" была на первой позиции, то есть первая по счёту, то далее она может быть только второй или третей. Если "2" была на третей позиции, то есть последней, то дальше она может быть только первой или второй, и т.д.

Comment: Это особо не проясняет. Кроме сдвигов, про которые вам ответили, есть и другие перестановки, в которых ни один элемент не остаётся на первоначальном месте, например, 2143. Впрочем, раз ответ принят - видимо, сдвиги вам и нужны.

Comment: @MBo , На самом деле, то что Вы описали больше мне подходит. Благодаря Вам я наконец-то смог правильно сформулировать запрос в гугл. Спасибо

Comment: Derangement это называется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @tym32167 за ответ. Добавил к этому коду шаффл и получил то, что хотел.

```
var data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5};
int count = 4;
var items = Shuffle(data).Select((d, i) => data.Concat(data).Skip(i).Take(count));
```

Сам шаффл:

```
static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    Random rng = new Random();
    int n = list.Count;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
        T value = list[k];
        list[k] = list[n];
        list[n] = value;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Разве случайная перестановка гарантирует, что результат будет без элементов на тех же местах?

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, у вас не все комбинации, а только все сдвиги.

Для генерации подобного нет необходимости в рекурсии, вот пример

```
var data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var items = data.Select((d, i) => data.Concat(data).Skip(i).Take(data.Length));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items.Select(x => string.Join(" ", x))));
```

Вывод

```
1 2 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
```